# How to concatenate DatetimeIndex objects in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's say I have 3 pandas [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) objects:

```py
import pandas as pd

idx1 = pd.date_range('2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00', freq='5T')
idx2 = pd.date_range('2019-01-01 02:00:00', '2019-01-01 03:00:00', freq='5T')
idx3 = pd.date_range('2019-01-02 00:00:00', '2019-01-02 01:00:00', freq='5T')
```

How can I combine them into a single index?

The roundabout way I do is by first converting them to [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), then using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) function to combine them, and then converting the series back to `DatetimeIndex`:

```py
# This works, but requires type conversions to and from
# intermediate series objects:
combined = pd.concat([idx1.to_series(), idx2.to_series(), idx3.to_series()])
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(combined.values)
```

Is there a direct way to combine indices in `pandas`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the clause 'union'.

```
combined = idx1.union(idx2).union(idx3)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this more generally for `n` indexes?

Comment: @mch56 if a_list is list of DatetimeIndex then 
```a_list[0].union_many(a_list[1:])```

Comment: @Mücahit Şenol thanks for this. Pandas is now deprecating this method and uses `union` instead. The input is either `DatetimeIndex` or array-like. So the correct approach now is `a_list[0].union(a_list[1:])`

Comment: @Mat Please not that while `union_many` is indeed deprecated (but works), `a_list[0].union(a_list[1:])` raises an error (tested with pandas 1.4 and 2.0).

Answer (score 4):

combined = idx1.union_many([idx2, idx3, ...])

Although Panda's documentation on this function says:

*A bit of a hack to accelerate unioning a collection of indexes*

Comment: This would have been the answer I was looking for but "DatetimeIndex.union_many is deprecated and will be removed in a future version." and it is very slow.

Answer (score 3):

In my case this is what I needed:

```py
ixfull = pd.DatetimeIndex(np.unique(np.hstack(ix_list)))
```

Since `union(a, b) = a + b - intersection(a, b) = unique(a + b)`. Verbose version below:

```py
fastunion = lambda x: np.unique(np.hstack(x))
def ixlist2ix(ix_list):
    ixunion = fastunion(ix_list)
    ixfull = pd.DatetimeIndex(ixunion)
    return ixfull
```

Comment: This method is slow compared to the pandas union method.

Comment: 1. union does not work on lists. 2. Iterating with union is much, much slower and union_many even slower.

Answer (score 1):

Following other answers, I did some speed benchmarking with random DateTimeIndexes.

Looks like despite the creation of numerous objects, casting to `Series`, `concat` and casting back is still the fastest option by far (x100 if unsorted) compared to `unions`. For sorted values, the solution of @Hunaphu is quicker but less readable. So, my solution would be:

```
res = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.concat([
    pd.Series(dti) 
    for dti in date_time_indexes
])).sort_values()
```

---

Benchmark code:

```py
start_range = pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01')
end_range = pd.Timestamp('2022-12-31')

date_time_indexes = []
for _ in range(100):
    start_date = pd.Timestamp(random.uniform(start_range.value, end_range.value))
    end_date = pd.Timestamp(random.uniform(start_date.value, end_range.value))
    freq = random.choice(['D', 'H', 'T'])
    dti = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq=freq)
    date_time_indexes.append(dti)

def cascaded_unions():
    res = date_time_indexes[0]
    for date_time_index in date_time_indexes[1:]:
        res = res.union(date_time_index)
    return res

res1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.concat([pd.Series(dti) for dti in date_time_indexes])) 
# timeit 60.6 ms
res2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(np.unique(np.hstack(date_time_indexes)))
# timeit 194 ms
res3 = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.concat([pd.Series(dti) for dti in date_time_indexes])).sort_values()
# timeit 417 ms
res4 = cascaded_unions()
# timeit 7.79 s
res5 = date_time_indexes[0].union_many(date_time_indexes[1:])
# timeit 7.86 s and is deprecated
```

Please note that method #1 returns an *unsorted* DateTimeIndex, hence method #3.